# Form breaks page

Tags: forms, contacts, xhtml-transitional

I coded a website, and am currently in the process of re-coding it. On my contact page, I have a form for questions, comments, etc. On the original website, the page works fine - however on the recode, the form breaks the page. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why.

Original page found here: http://path-to-truth.org/contact/

Recode found here: http://path-to-truth.org/Recode/contact/

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? Style? Positioning of elements? Does it not submit correctly?

Comment: Positioning. When I take the form out, the header is correct. When I add it back in, the page distorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul#nav` has a `margin-right` of 7% in your style.css file. When I remove that, it looks normal. The margin is added to the right of the navigation. Because that make the block too large for the header, it moves down. Because you have `float:right` on that element also, it is put to the right of the `h1`.

Another option would be to remove the `float: right` on the navigation and put `float: left` on the image (or the `a` tag). At the bottom of your `div#header`, insert (inside the div) a new div with `clear: both` to pull the header region down.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! However, now the logo doesn't align properly with the text on the home screen (I'm slightly OCD in that I can't /not/ fix that) but that's simple enough to remedy. Again, thank you! :D